# Get the own process pid from the command prompt in windows

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I'm trying to get the PID from command prompt of its own. But when using the below command i'm not getting the desired output always. Can you please point out what was the error in the below statement?

```
cmd.exe /c title="mycmd" & tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "mycmd" & dir & help
```

**Edit:**

The below command working correctly. But when combine it with two more commands. It's not working.

```
cmd.exe /c title="mycmd" & tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "mycmd"
```

**Additional Info:**

I'm using Java

```
final List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();                

commands.add("cmd.exe");
commands.add("/C");

//.. Add more commands

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
```

Comment: why do you need the dir and help commands to get the PID?

Comment: @galuano1: I'm executing different commands that was specific to my project. But for example i have posted dir and help commands.

Comment: The problem is a typo.  You're setting the title to "mycmd" but searching for "my cmd" (which actually searches for either "my" or "cmd").

Comment: If i change to mycmd also it's not working.

Comment: Note that in Windows you don't need to build the command in pieces as an array, although you can if it's convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the PID of the cmd prompt using below batch file.

**Reference:**  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/270f0842-963d-4ed9-b27d-27957628004c/

**GetPID.bat**

```
@echo off
if not defined SESSIONNAME set SESSIONNAME=Console
setlocal
set instance=%DATE% %TIME% %RANDOM%
title %instance%
for /f "usebackq tokens=2" %%a in (`tasklist /FO list /FI "SESSIONNAME eq %SESSIONNAME%" /FI "USERNAME eq %USERNAME%" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %instance%" ^| find /i "PID:"`)
    do set PID=%%a
if not defined PID for /f "usebackq tokens=2" %%a in (`tasklist /FO list /FI "SESSIONNAME eq %SESSIONNAME%" /FI "USERNAME eq %USERNAME%" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:  %instance%" ^| find /i "PID:"`)
    do set PID=%%a
if not defined PID
 echo !Error: Could not determine the Process ID of the current script.  Exiting.& exit /b 1
echo PID: "%PID%"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around the composite command to be executed in the subshell:

```
cmd.exe /c "title="mycmd" & tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "mycmd" & dir & help"
```

Without the quotes, the command is parsed as

```
(cmd.exe /c title="mycmd") & (tasklist /v /fo /csv) | (findstr /i "mycmd") & (dir) & (help)
```

so by the time `tasklist` runs the instance of `cmd.exe` with the specified title has already exited.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a few redirection operator. Read more [here.](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Can you please let me know what redirection operator I'm missing?

Comment: read here. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

Give the CMD window an unique name, in this example "test".
The "Windowstitle" is "test*" because the executed command line will be attached to the title.

```
title test
taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne test*" /f
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to also use the domain with the user name.

```
    @IF NOT DEFINED SESSIONNAME (@SET SESSIONNAME=Console)
    @SETLOCAL
    @SET EXITCODE=0
    @SET instance=%DATE% %TIME% %RANDOM%
    @TITLE %instance%

    @FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%a IN (`tasklist /FO list /FI "SESSIONNAME eq %SESSIONNAME%" /FI "USERNAME eq %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %instance%" ^| FIND /I "PID:"`) DO @(
        @SET PID=%%b
    )

    @IF NOT DEFINED PID (
        @FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%a IN (`tasklist /FO list /FI "SESSIONNAME eq %SESSIONNAME%" /FI "USERNAME eq %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:  %instance%" ^| FIND /I "PID:"`) DO @(
            @SET PID=%%b
        )
    )

    @IF NOT DEFINED PID (
        @ECHO ERROR: Could not determine the Process ID of the current script.
        @SET EXITCODE=1
    ) ELSE (
        @ECHO %PID%
    )

    @EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```